# Laravel Routing URL

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.7

I want to make a routing on laravel `{{ route('import',[$p->id]) }}` this are on my `a href` but when my cursor hovering on the button it preview `import?1` not `import/2` what is my mistake here?

Answer (score 2):

In routes you should name the routes and pass the parameters there as well. For example

```
Route::get('/import/{id}','AnyController@controllerFunction')->name('import');
```

Then in views you can call the route function as you did.

```
{{ route('import',[$p->id]) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define route as `->name('import')` or `'as'=>'import'` here.

```
Route::get('import/{id}','Controller@method')->name('import');
```

**Or**

```
Route::get('import/{id}',['as'=>'import','uses'=>'Controller@method']);
```

In href you can call as

```
<a href="{{ route('import',[$p->id]) }}">CLick</a>
```

If the named route defines parameters, you may pass the parameters as the second argument to the **route** function. The given parameters will automatically be inserted into the URL in their correct positions:

```
Route::get('user/{id}/profile', function ($id) {
    //
})->name('profile');

$url = route('profile', ['id' => 1]);

//Url will be domain.com/user/1/profile.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
{{ route('import/'.$projects->id) }}
```